# Performance of site significantly dropped, reason unknown

Tags: html, wordpress, performance, google-analytics, web

I normally leave a website alone and check every now and then after it is finished. I wasn't paying attention to my google analytics, and then on april 18-20 there is a significant drop on number of users & the bounce rate became 100%.

I'm a web developer by profession, and i didn't spot anything wrong.
The site doesn't seem to be hacked, and just before i reinstall everything (files and DB), I wanted to ask if you can find something is wrong with it?

Site in question
http://www.graciesingapore.com/

Regards,
Jairus

Answer (score 0):

The site loads a lot of different javascript and css files, maybe you can try a caching plugin like [WP-Rocket](https://wp-rocket.me/) or [WP Fastest Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/) to bundle and cache the files.

Answer (score 0):

Ask some questions...

- When you put the site live, was the performance good?
- If it was what changed in-between then and now?
- Was it an automated core/plugin/theme update that slowed down the
  site?
- What happened to traffic after 20th April?
- Did bounce rate decrease and visitors increase?
- What do your server logs show for the 18th to the 20th?
- etc etc...

Your site does load a ton of resources and on the [programs page](http://www.graciesingapore.com/gracie-curriculums/) there are two images each [over 1MB](https://i.imgur.com/2jo8lsH.png) that load in. Try WP Smush over your media folder